# How to use timer in C#?

Tags: c#

I want my function to be executed every 2 seconds to check if there is any new user so that I could make a new log for them. This is in console application so i used Thread. But my console shut down after it run the function once. I am expecting the timer to run as long as I am running the console and my createLog function will be executed every 2 seconds. I am relatively new to C# so maybe my concept of timer is completely wrong. Please help...

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Hashtable clientsList = new Hashtable();


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer t = new Timer(createLog, null, 0, 2000);


            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(ip, 9888);
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            int counter = 0;

            serverSocket.Start();
            .... //this main is monitoring the network....
           console.read();
        }



 private static void createLog(object state)
        {
         //this function checks the database and if there is new user it will create a new text file for he/she. 

        }
  }
```

Comment: What Timer class are you using?

Comment: You meant <
using System.Threading;>?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a console app you need to add something like `Console.ReadLine()` to keep the app alive until the user wants to shut it down.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [FluentScheduler](http://fluentscheduler.codeplex.com/documentation) can help.

```
using FluentScheduler;

public class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyRegistry()
    {
        // Schedule an ITask to run at an interval
        Schedule<MyTask>().ToRunNow().AndEvery(2).Seconds();

        // Schedule a simple task to run at a specific time
        Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Timed Task - Will run every day at 9:15pm: " + DateTime.Now)).ToRunEvery(1).Days().At(21, 15);

        // Schedule a more complex action to run immediately and on an monthly interval
        Schedule(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Complex Action Task Starts: " + DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Complex Action Task Ends: " + DateTime.Now);
        }).ToRunNow().AndEvery(1).Months().OnTheFirst(DayOfWeek.Monday).At(3, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i would like to stick with timer

Answer (score 0):

Winforms/Console apps ->  [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

WPF -> [Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Comment: OP detailed console application

Comment: first link compares 3 timers, all of which can be used in Console/Winform apps.

Answer (score 0):

You need a blocking call like `Console.ReadLine` after calling `Start` to keep the foreground thread running. Also, the your Timer is eligible for garbage collection because it is not referenced again after it is created. Use `GC.KeepAlive` at the end of the Main method to prevent the timer from being GC'd.

Comment: I dont think that is the problem. I deleted the Timer object and my console work fine, it does want i want, but once i added the timer object then the console shut down

Comment: @qwrqwr Is there an exception in the `createLog` method? What happens if you just call the `createLog` method without the Timer? The code you have shown us executes every two seconds on my machine, without stopping until I hit enter.